# jquery function to sum textboxes that have 2 classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add up a group of textboxes using jquery. Each textbox has a class (class1) to style it using bootstrap. I am adding an additional class (class2) to run the jquery function. Here is a sample of how two of the textboxes look.

```
<input type="text" class="class1 class2" name="textbox1" id="textbox1 />
<input type="test" class="class1 class2" name="textbox2" id="textbox2 />
```

And here is my jquery function. GrandTotal is the id of the textbox to hold the sum.

```
$('.class2').keyup(function () { 
  var sum = 0;

  $('.class2').each(function() {
    sum += Number($(this).val());
  });

  $('#GrandTotal').val(sum);

});
```

It's not working. I get no result in #GrandTotal. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance for your help.

cdr6800

Comment: This should work! Where is `#GrandTotal` ?

Comment: #GrandTotal is the id of the textbox that holds the sum. It is in the html code. When I update textbox1 or 2, GrandTotal does change, but it changes each time I hit the tab key and keeps adding. Maybe keyup is not the correct type of function? Thanks.

Comment: If you would like to see what I am talking about, you can go to https://www.pfacmeeting.org/badgeform2.php and enter 1 in the first Quantity text box. $50 will drop to the GrandTotal when you tab out of that box, but when you tab through the others, it keeps adding $50 to the GrandTotal.

Answer (score 2):

You must validate that input is numeric, otherwise you will get NaN (not a number). JavaScript has `isNaN()` function for checking the given input is NaN or not.

```
$('input.class2').keyup(function() {
  var sum = 0;

  $('input.class2').each(function() {
    var value = Number($(this).val());
    if(!isNaN(value)) {
        sum += value;
    }
  });

  $('#GrandTotal').val(sum);
});
```

See it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/ibrahimeymenduran/ymnu9hf4/

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is not valid.

```
<input type="test" class="class1 class2" name="textbox2" id="textbox2 />
```

► **type= "text" not "test"**

► **You haven't close the id with a double quotes.**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.class2').keyup(function() {
    var sum = 0;

    $('.class2').each(function() {
      sum += Number($(this).val());
    });

    $('#GrandTotal').val(sum);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="class1 class2" name="textbox1" id="textbox1">
<input type=" text " class="class1 class2 " name="textbox2 " id="textbox2">
<input type=" text " name="textbox3 " id="GrandTotal">
```

Comment: That doesn't matter. If a type of an input element is not supplied or invalid, then that will be considered as text.

Comment: yes...I see that, but that is just a sample. I used "text" in the real case. I just had a typo. Thanks for finding that though.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy I was just pointing out the mistakes to OP so that he can improve. :)

Comment: Thank you Rino. It generally works...but is it possible to have GrandTotal update at the same time textbox1 or 2 updates? Right now, you have to tab through it in order for GrandTotal to update. If you want to see what I mean, please go to www.pfacmeeting.org/badgeform2.php and put numbers in the Quantity column. It looks like it is working that way in your example though. Not sure why it does not work that way on my page. Here is the jquery code:Thanks.

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {

      $('.class2').keyup(function() {
        var sum = 0;

        $('.class2').each(function() {
          sum += Number($(this).val());
        });

        $('#GrandTotal').val((sum).toFixed(2));

      });
    });

Answer (score 1):

You can do it even without jQuery, in plain JavaScript.

```js
var GrandTotal = document.getElementById("GrandTotal");
var values = [0, 0];

function updateTotal(element, index) {
  element.onkeyup = function() {
    if (!isNaN(element.value)) {
      values[index] = parseInt(element.value || 0);
    }
    GrandTotal.textContent = values[0] + values[1];
  }
}

Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('class2'), updateTotal);
```

```html
<input type="text" class="class1 class2" name="textbox1" id="textbox1" />
<input type="test" class="class1 class2" name="textbox2" id="textbox2" />
<p id="GrandTotal"></p>
```

- `Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('class2')).forEach(updateTotal);` gets you an array of elements with class `class2`. `forEach` calls `updateTotal` for every one of them.
- `updateTotal` takes `element` which will be element that has changed and `index` to indicate if it is the first or second one of your `<input/>`s.
- Inside `element.onkeyup` we check if the given `<input/>` holds non-NaN value. If it is so, we put the numeric value (or 0) on appropriate position in `values` array. Then we update `#GrandTotal`'s text.

That way, value of `#GrandTotal` will be always updated with every `<input/>`'s change unless it will change to invalid value, in which case it will hold the last valid value for it.